# Randomisation uneven in a choice experiment - what could help to overcome associated problems?

Tags: choice-modeling

We conducted a choice experiment of the type forced-choice, choose between A or B. A or B are products that are described using 5 attributes. These 5 attributes have different attribute levels that describe the options.
In my example they are cars. They have a price (attribute) with levels in $, they have the attribute (colour) with its levels "blue" "black" and "green", they have mileage (some values from 5-15 litres/km). And there is the attribute convertible "yes" or "no".

All of these attribute values were randomly assigned - but the randomisation had a flow. While all attributes have nearly equally distributed attribute levels one has not (see picture attached, all bars should have ideally been around the same length through randomisation and law  of large n). However, it isn't.

The screenshot shows flawed in randomisation the different levels of milage on the left and on the right one of the correctly randomised variables price

But the experiment was fielded with this flawed data and I have to work with the results.

Is there any way of weighing or analysing only a subset that is "good in terms of randomisation" in order to overcome this problem?

I wanted to estimate a logit model of choice for car given these attributes and their levels, but the problem was that using the mlogit package in R, I always got a fatal error as soon as I entered the mileage attribute (the one with the "funny" distribution). Using all the others as predictors works perfectly fine.

[image: The screenshot shows flawed in randomisation the different levels of milage on the left and on the right one of the correctly randomised variables price]